# 2D UiLabel Grid with UIStackView last column not filling up space. Does UIStackView honor ContentHuggingPriority?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uistackview

I am trying to make an UIControl that is easier to make a grid than using the UICollectionView for certain small tasks. I am using UIStackView of UIStackViews. That is a horizontal container of vertical stacks(Columns). The problem is I need one column to be expansion column for filling extra space. Does UIStackView honor the setting of setContentHuggingPriority for itself ? , in this case one of my vertical columns.

I have included a playground to recreate this problem.

[Link to visual showing the UILabel Grid where only one column should fill horizontally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtCg8.jpg)

Here is playground code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class ViewController : UIViewController {
    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        self.view = view

        let labMatrix = LabelMatrix( rows: 4, columns: 4)

        self.view.addSubview( labMatrix)

        labMatrix.labMatrix[0][0].text = "Test"
        labMatrix.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 360, height: 520)
    }
}

class LabelMatrix : UIStackView {
    let rowCount : Int
    let colCount : Int

    var labMatrix = [[UILabel]]()

    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    init ( rows: Int , columns : Int ) {
        rowCount = rows
        colCount = columns
        super.init(frame:.zero)
        create()
    }

    func create() {
        var columns : [UIStackView] = [UIStackView]()
        var rows : [UILabel] = [UILabel]()

        for acol in 0..<colCount {
            rows.removeAll()

            for arow in 0..<rowCount {
                let lab = UILabel()
                //                lab.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                rows.append( lab )

                let str = "(\(arow),\(acol))"
                lab.text = str

                if !(arow%2 == 0) {
                    lab.backgroundColor = .lightGray
                } else {
                    lab.backgroundColor = .yellow
                }

                if arow == rowCount-1 {
                    print("This should make last row stretch vertically to fill any extra vertical space")
                    //                    lab.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 20), for: .vertical)
                    lab.setContentHuggingPriority(UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 20), for:.vertical)
                }
            }

            labMatrix.append( rows )
            let curCol = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: rows)
            columns.append( curCol )

            curCol.axis = .vertical
            curCol.distribution = .fill
            curCol.spacing = 2
            curCol.alignment = .center

            if acol == colCount-1 {
                print("TODO Fix This. It should make only the last column(e.g. uistackview) strech to fill extra space")
                curCol.setContentHuggingPriority(UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 20), for:.horizontal)
            }
        }

        for col in columns {
            self.addArrangedSubview( col )
        }

        self.axis = .horizontal
        self.distribution = .fill
        self.alignment = .top
        self.spacing = 4
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ViewController()
```

Answer (score 0):

Stack views behave a bit differently than other views in a number of ways - compression and hugging are two notable ones.

A stack view's primary function is to *arrange its subviews*. When one or more of its subviews has its own size / compression / hugging properties, the stack view's layout will be determined (in part) by its subviews.

To get your last column (and last row) to expand, the distribution needs to be `fill` and the views (labels) in that column / row need their hugging priorities modified.

You can get this playground result:

[image]

by modifying your code as below (comments should be clear):

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class ViewController : UIViewController {
    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        self.view = view

        let labMatrix = LabelMatrix( rows: 4, columns: 4)

        self.view.addSubview( labMatrix)

        labMatrix.labMatrix[0][0].text = "Test"
        labMatrix.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 360, height: 520)
    }
}

class LabelMatrix : UIStackView {
    let rowCount : Int
    let colCount : Int

    var labMatrix = [[UILabel]]()

    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    init ( rows: Int , columns : Int ) {
        rowCount = rows
        colCount = columns
        super.init(frame:.zero)
        create()
    }

    func create() {
        var columns : [UIStackView] = [UIStackView]()
        var rows : [UILabel] = [UILabel]()

        for acol in 0..<colCount {
            rows.removeAll()

            for arow in 0..<rowCount {
                let lab = UILabel()
                rows.append( lab )

                let str = "(\(arow),\(acol))"
                lab.text = str

                // set the label text alignment to center
                lab.textAlignment = .center

                if !(arow%2 == 0) {
                    lab.backgroundColor = .lightGray
                } else {
                    lab.backgroundColor = .yellow
                }

                if acol == colCount-1 {
                    print("This will allow the last column to stretch horizontally")
                    lab.setContentHuggingPriority(UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 20), for:.horizontal)
                }

                if arow == rowCount-1 {
                    print("This will allow the bottom row stretch vertically")
                    lab.setContentHuggingPriority(UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 20), for:.vertical)
                }

            }

            labMatrix.append( rows )
            let curCol = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: rows)
            columns.append( curCol )

            curCol.axis = .vertical
            curCol.distribution = .fill
            curCol.spacing = 2
            // .alignment should be .fill -- let the label center its own text
            curCol.alignment = .fill

            // not needed - hugging priority is controlled by the stack view's arranged subviews
            // if acol == colCount-1 {
            //  print("TODO Fix This. It should make only the last column(e.g. uistackview) strech to fill extra space")
            //  curCol.setContentHuggingPriority(UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 20), for:.horizontal)
            // }

        }

        for col in columns {
            self.addArrangedSubview( col )
        }

        self.axis = .horizontal
        self.distribution = .fill
        // .alignment needs to be .fill if you want the bottom row to expand vertically
        self.alignment = .fill
        self.spacing = 4
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ViewController()
```

Comment: I just wanted to say your code change is a huge improvement . The last columns text can be left justified but the bottom row's text is stranded in the middle of the filled space. When I placed your change in a custom UITableViewCell it did something funny but I need to test it again and if it is repeatable post it. But Thanks for this huge improvement.

Comment: I'm sure you found it easy to change the last column to left-justified. The comment in your code indicated you wanted the bottom row to fill the space... if you don't, change  `self.alignment` back to `.top`, and you don't need the `lab.setContentHuggingPriority` in your `if arow == rowCount-1` block. Generally, if you don't want the stack view to **fill** its bounds, don't constrain its height (via frame or activated constraints) and let its content determine its height.